# Behat configuration of behat.tml for crossbrowser testing

Tags: drupal-7, cross-browser, behat

I am using behat 3. My behat.yml looks like the following

```
default:
  suites:
    default:
      contexts:
        - Drupal\DrupalExtension\Context\MinkContext
        - FeatureContext
extensions:
  Behat\MinkExtension:
    goutte: ~
    selenium2: ~
    javascript_session:  'selenium2'
    browser_name: chrome
  Drupal\DrupalExtension:
    blackbox: ~
    region_map:
      search: ".form-search"
    api_driver: "drupal"
    selectors:
      message_selector: '.messages'
      error_message_selector: '.messages.messages-error'
      success_message_selector: '.messages.messages-status'
imports:
  - behat.local.yml
```

behat.local.yml looks like:

```
default:
  extensions:
    Behat\MinkExtension:
      # Replace with your real URL.
      base_url: http://website.com
    Drupal\DrupalExtension:
      drupal:
        drupal_root: "/home/website"
```

How can I make this run against internet explorer? Fyi I am using phantomjs to fake the browsers on the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After googling a bit I found out that you can just replicate the profiles in the following way:

```
default:
  suites:
    default:
      contexts:
        - FeatureContext
        - Drupal\DrupalExtension\Context\DrupalContext
        - Drupal\DrupalExtension\Context\MessageContext
        - Drupal\DrupalExtension\Context\MinkContext
        - Drupal\DrupalExtension\Context\MarkupContext
      filters:
        tags: "@blackbox"
      extensions:
        Behat\MinkExtension:
          goutte: ~
          zombie: ~
          base_url: http://drupal.org
          javascript_session: zombie
        Drupal\DrupalExtension:
          blackbox: ~
          region_map:
            content: "#content"
            footer: "#footer"
            left header: "#header-left"
            right header: "#header-right"
            right sidebar: "#aside-region"
          selectors:
            message_selector: '.messages'
            error_message_selector: '.messages.error'
            success_message_selector: '.messages.status'
            warning_message_selector: '.messages.warning'

# Separate profile for testing using the api driver. This assumes a
# stock Drupal 6 install.
drupal6:
  suites:
    default:
      contexts:
        - FeatureContext
        - Drupal\DrupalExtension\Context\DrupalContext
        - Drupal\DrupalExtension\Context\MinkContext
        - Drupal\DrupalExtension\Context\MarkupContext
      filters:
      tags: "@d6"
    extensions:
      Behat\MinkExtension:
        base_url: http://127.0.0.1:8888
      Drupal\DrupalExtension:
        api_driver: "drupal"
        drupal:
        # Change this to the absolute path to Drupal install.
          drupal_root: "drupal"
        region_map:
          left sidebar: "#sidebar-first"
```

Check this [drupalextension blob](https://github.com/jhedstrom/drupalextension/blob/5eec9d6fbbf1f2185cfb20b67ca5deb226af0838/behat.yml.dist)